# Sentiment Analysis algorithm in Weka

Tags: classification, weka

I have an assignment, i have to collect movie reviews and classify them with poz neg notr tags, and turn them info arff files. I did all of this stuff with regex etc.

But for experiment i have to choose ten classify algorithm. I did some research but couldn't figure out which algortihm should i use.

Can you please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial here:

http://www.unal.edu.co/diracad/einternacional/Weka.pdf

Basically you want to use a StringToWordVector filter to convert your string into word vectors (!) and then train a Bayes classifier on that data.